Is Holy Terra Earth?
I always assumed Holy Terra, site of the Golden Throne and ostensible capital planet of the Imperium was far future Earth but something I read on another site has led me to question it- are they in fact the same planet?

What did you read on what other site to question that Terra = Earth?

@user14111- a page on 1d6chan, which referred to Terra as "most likely the planet on which you currently reside".

In science fiction the word Terra has always (for over 100 years) referred to the planet Earth. Earth has occasionally had other names (such as Tellus) but Terra has never been anything else. Perhaps that "most likely" allows for the possibility that the reader is residing on some other planet.

I was hoping to get a nice canonical reference for a proper answer - but the wiki doesn't really do that: https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Terra

But, essentially, Earth is Terra. There are references to Jermani, Merica, and Britannia (bastardised through 40,000 years). The first world colonised was Mars, followed by the rest of Sol (the solar system). Pretty sure the Himalayas are mentioned, too

For those who are unfamiliar with 1d4chan/1d6chan, keep in mind that things you can read on that website should be taken with a grain of humour/salt/sarcasm most of the time.

@HorusKol - This is the link you want... https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Age_of_Terra#:~:text=The%20Age%20of%20Terra%2C%20also,star%2Dspanning%20Fusion%20Age%20civilisation.

1d6chan is a joke/satire site. It says "most likely" because maybe you're in space when you're reading it.

I believe that perhaps around 3rd edition there was a map in a rulebook which incidentally showed the location of the Golden Throne, which just so happened to be (approximately) the location of Games Workshop's first HQ. Vague memory, lack of source, so a comment.

Terra is simply the Latin word for Earth. It's the same as calling it "heilige Erde" or "Santa tierra". We are all Terrans -- a fact, as an aside, that is all too often forgotten ;-).

@Nu'Daq probably someone trying to stay in character and to be future proof :)

The Core Rulebook for Warhammer 40K explicitly states that the Emperor was born on Earth and even gives his approximate date of birth and location of birth.

THE EMPEROR IS BORN
Of the birth and early life of the Emperor we shall say only a little, for space does not permit us to examine every detail of a life-time spanning almost fifty thousand years. His mother and father were human, his brothers and sisters were mortals like any other, so when he was bom his parents had no reason to think of him as anything other than a normal human child.
Only much later would he identify the time of his birth as the eighth millennium BC or the place as Central Anatolia, and by then he would have almost forgotten his early life among the barren mountains and cold streams.

and

On Earth the well ordered civilisations of the past were gone. Government had degenerated into global anarchy. From that anarchy the Emperor emerged - a saviour in the time of ultimate crisis. He led armies from the Antartic to Greenland, from the deserts of Amazonia to the mountains of Africa, his followers ever growing in number and strength. His message was clear and vital: unite humanity and bring order to the galaxy.

The Emperor is stated to have his Golden throne on Earth.

THE GOLDEN THRONE
The fight with Horus was waged both in the material universe and in the warp, their bodies and their spirits battling for survival. The Emperor’s body was all but destroyed, and his psychic powers were also dealt a severe blow. The forces of Chaos melted away. Some of those not too long in the service of Chaos were suddenly free from its illusions and quickly switched sides, fighting with all the more vigour in their attempts to make amends for their treachery. Others whose corruption was more deeply rooted, seeing that all was lost, retreated to their ships and fled into open space. The Emperor’s body was hastily returned to Earth and placed in a life-preserving bubble.
The life support unit known as the Golden Throne was quickly built to encase the Emperor. His powers survived, but his body was shattered. At first he was able to communicate semi-coherently for brief periods, later he lapsed into complete silence. That silence has remained undisturbed now for almost ten thousand years.


Now that you mention it, yeah, the Golden Throne is located inside the Himalayan mountains, isn't it? https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_Palace

The prologue of The Outcast Dead confirms that Terra was known in antiquity as "Earth".
Note also that it has a moon called Luna, a star called Sol, and a neighbouring planet called Mars.

The 2003-released Games Workshop-licensed game Warhammer 40,000: Fire Warrior has a beautiful intro in which the exact line "[…] Terra, known to antiquity as earth," is mentioned. Notably earlier than the 2011-released 17th Horus Heresy book.




Amazing intro. Awful game.
